# Change archivelog location in Oracle

Tags: oracle, log-shipping

Oracle instance I set up is using USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST for archivelog location.

```
log_archive_dest_1                   string
```

`LOCATION=use_db_recovery_file_
dest, valid_for=(ALL_ROLES,ALL
_LOGFILES)`

I want to specify the exact location. Old and new location is same, only need to specify the path. I cannot restart the database as it is production server. Is there any way I can do it without restarting the database

Comment: look at the manuals [Specifying Archive Destinations](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/archredo.htm#ADMIN11338) , [LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-10BD97BF-6295-4E85-A1A3-854E15E05A44.htm#REFRN10086)

Comment: I saw it. My question is if there is a way to apply it without restarting database.

Comment: Yes, you can modify it without restarting the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the manuals [Specifying Archive Destinations](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/archredo.htm#ADMIN11338),[LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-10BD97BF-6295-4E85-A1A3-854E15E05A44.htm#REFRN10086). But they are unclear about if it is possible to change it online.

1. Try it out on a test instance. You always should try out thinks on a test instance. Especially if you are using some tips from the internet.
2. If you an `alter system set = ... scope=both;` and the parameter cannot be specified in memory, you get a

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02095: specified initialization parameter cannot be modified
```

error, but nothing bad happens. So you can try it out if the parameter is specified in memory.

3. I tried to set the parameter to the value already set and it worked

```
SQL> alter system set log_archive_dest_1=
  2  'location=USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST, valid_for=(ALL_LOGFILES,ALL_ROLES)'
  3  scope=both;

System altered.

SQL>
```

If you change the destination for the archives and there are still archives in the old destination then the database knows this an therefore RMAN knows this and will not forget them but backup them when you do your next archive log backup.

Comment: Thanks @miracle173 . I forgot to set scope to both. I was only setting to spfile that's why it hasnt been showing up when I query

Comment: +1 for answering and not referring folks to the Oracle docs.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `sysdba` login credentials and just enter this

```
SQL> alter system set LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1='LOCATION=C:\u01\app\oradata\ORCL\archive VALID_FOR=(ALL_LOGFILES,ALL_ROLES) DB_UNIQUE_NAME=orcl';

System altered.

SQL>

C:\u01\app\oradata\ORCL\archive is your custom location
```

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

It is not possible to change the location of archive log destination without restarting the database. If the you provide the scope as `memory` they you will get an error.

And if you provide the scope as `spfile`, then you need yo restart the database.

So I think you need to ask some downtime as do the operation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect. `LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n` can be modified without a restart, even with `scope=memory`.

Comment: Well I tried, I got the error. Can you please put the statement with the snapshot.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cZQAFTk5

Comment: @BalazsPapp check the edit and kindly tell me if its still possible. I have tried with double quotes also. It does not work. If my answer is wrong please suggest me what else can be done.

Comment: @Jeethu: if the parameter is not modifieable in meory , you get a different answer, see (2) from my answer. If you want an answer why your commands do not work open another  question but please do not use this  question to investigation of your problems

Comment: @miracle173 sorry for the inconvenience. But all I did not intend to cause any trouble. Your answer is right. And there is no other way other than your method. I apologize if I caused trouble.

Comment: You tried `log_archive_dest`, and that is deprecated in favor of `log_archive_dest_n`.

Comment: `log_archive_dest_n` wont work either... `miracle173` answer is right. I used alter `system set log_archive_dest_1='location=USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST' scope=both;` and it worked.